# Making API Calls Within Alexa Intent Handler

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an Alexa skill that makes an API call to retrieve weather data. No matter what I've tried I can't get this code to work. This seems like the kind of thing that wouldn't be hard, I just can't figure out how to fit the API call into the intent handler. It probably doesn't help that my Node skills are rusty too...

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint quote-props: ["error", "consistent"]*/
/**
 * This sample demonstrates a simple skill built with the Amazon Alexa Skills
 * nodejs skill development kit.
 * This sample supports multiple lauguages. (en-US, en-GB, de-DE).
 * The Intent Schema, Custom Slots and Sample Utterances for this skill, as well
 * as testing instructions are located at https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact
 **/

'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

//Replace with your app ID (OPTIONAL).  You can find this value at the top of your skill's page on http://developer.amazon.com.
//Make sure to enclose your value in quotes, like this: const APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.bb4045e6-b3e8-4133-b650-72923c5980f1';
const APP_ID = undefined;

const SKILL_NAME = 'Space Facts';
const GET_FACT_MESSAGE = "Here's your fact: ";
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me a space fact, or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('GetWeatherIntent');
    },
    'GetWeatherIntent': function () {
        var mythis=this;
        var city=this.event.request.intent.slots.city.value;

        var weather='{"coord":{"lon":-104.98,"lat":39.74},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":300.92,"pressure":1012,"humidity":23,"temp_min":297.15,"temp_max":303.15},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":360},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1527451080,"sys":{"type":1,"id":539,"message":0.0055,"country":"US","sunrise":1527420953,"sunset":1527473936},"id":5419384,"name":"Denver","cod":200}';

        getWeather(city, function (output) {
            weather=output;
            var speechText = 'The temperature in ';
            speechText += mythis.event.request.intent.slots.city.value;
            speechText += ' is ';
            speechText += toFahrenheit(JSON.parse(weather).main.temp);
            speechText += ' degrees ';
            speechText += 'Fahrenheit'; //TODO: add Celsius capability
            mythis.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, speechText);
            mythis.response.speak(speechText);
            mythis.emit(':responseReady');
            mythis.emit(output);
        });



    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        const speechOutput = HELP_MESSAGE;
        const reprompt = HELP_REPROMPT;

        this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};

var getTemp = function (city) {
    return getWeather(city).main.temp;
}

var getWeather = function(city, callback) {
    var URL='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&APPID=[MY API KEY]';
    const https = require('https');

    https.get(URL, (res, callback) => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:', res.headers);

        var output='';

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            output += d;
        });

        res.on('end', callback(output));

    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
}

var toFahrenheit = function(kelvins) {
    return Math.round(9.0/5.0*(kelvins-273)+32);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler for the 'end' event is at the wrong position, one way you could write your function (reading the buffer from https.get with JSON.parse and calling the callback with the result):

```
var getWeather = function(city, callback) {
  const url='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&APPID=<your api key>';
  const https = require('https');

  https.get(url, res => {
    var output='';

    res.on('data', d => {
      output += d;
    });
    res.on('error', console.error);
    res.on('end', () => {
      callback(JSON.parse(output))
    });
  });
}


// example usage: 
getWeather('london', res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```